# How to do this XML REST request in vb.net

Tags: xml, vb.net, rest, restful-authentication

How do I post this HTTP REST request using HttpWebRequest and System.Xml.XmlDocument in vb.net

```
<tns:request command="hello" xmlns:tns="http://www.xxyyzz.com/xx/yy/zz" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" />
```

The server responds with

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><response xmlns="http://www.xxyyzz.com/xx/yy/zz"><operation location="/mm/10d9c79e-5876-4fd0-9093-ff7bdee5ebd4/uploadInfo" command="uploadInfo"/></response>
```

how do I capture this response?

Answer (score 0):

The `.GetResponse` method returns the repsonse from the server.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.getresponse.aspx#Y1665